# Why doesnt the page scroll down?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

So, this is a simples question. Why, even thougth i have a div that overtakes the length of window, i cant scroll down the page to see the rest of what that div contains? Never happened to me, tried to search some things but i cant find. I put all code because i dont know if its something of <meta name ....

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<title>ITW 2021/22 - Driver Details</title>
<link href="Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css">
<link href ="../Content/bootstrap-reboot.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="#">
<style>
    .styles {
        height: 400px;
        width: 500px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #index {
        background-size: cover;
        background-image: url("https://images5.alphacoders.com/317/thumb-1920-317664.jpg");
        background-position: top;
        position: fixed;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }
</style>
</head>
    <body id="index">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-opacity-10 fixed-top py-3" style="position:relative">
    <div class="container px-4 px-lg-5">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
            <img style="height:50px; width:65px;" src="img/f1-abu-dhabi-gp-2017-f1-logo-6614911-removebg-preview.png" />
        </a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto my-2 my-lg-0">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="home.html" style="color:white"><b>Home</b></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Circuits.html" style="color: white"><b>Circuits</b></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Drivers.html" style="color: white"><b>Drivers</b></a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="Timeline.html" style="color: white"><b>Champions</b></a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <a style="color: white" class="btn dropdown-toggle" href="#" role="button" id="dropdownMenuLink" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                </a>

                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="FAQs.html">FAQ's</a></li>
                    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="AboutUs.html">About us</a></li>

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<br />


<div class="row" style="margin:auto">
    <div class="container d-flex flex-row" style="margin:auto; min-width:50px; max-width: 600px">
        <div class="py-3 container"><input class="form-control" Id="SearchText" placeholder="Search circuit" /></div>
        <div class="py-3 container"><button type="button" id="clickCir" class="btn btn-secondary">Search</button></div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-none text-danger col-form-label container" id="NomeError">
        <center><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i><b>É necessário selecionar um circuito</b></center>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="margin:auto; background-color:white; max-width:900px; min-height:900px; border-radius:10px;">
    <div class="container" id="infoId" style="margin:auto; justify-content:center"> </div>
</div>

<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/knockout-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui-1.13.0.js"></script>
<script src="Circuit.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of your `#index { }` delete `position: fixed;` to be able to scroll.

Comment: Many thx, i think i didnt pay attention to that detail.

Comment: Don't worry, we all do that sometimes. It's natural.